# Setting Up Usable IPS on Debian

Tags: debian, nic

I have a dedicated machine that I am renting with 5 usable IP. The only issue is that only one IP is set up to be public and I'm trying to get the others to be public. I've tried following a few guides and I have had a few issues.

I know I have to edit the file entitled "interfaces" in /etc/network but I don't know what to add because I changed it before and lost all connection to my server and had to have my host fix it. my IP range goes from xxx.xxx.xx.114 - xxx.xxx.xx.118 The file is currently as follows:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xx.114
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    gateway xxx.xxx.xx.113
    dns-nameservers 192.187.107.16 69.30.209.16
```

How do I go about getting the other ips opened up publicly?

Answer (score 3):

Do it the easy way, by adding the additional addresses to the interface after it is brought up:

```
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.0.2.114
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.0.2.1
  up ip addr add 192.0.2.115/24 dev eth0
  up ip addr add 192.0.2.116/24 dev eth0
  up ip addr add 192.0.2.117/24 dev eth0
  up ip addr add 192.0.2.118/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: I would recommand adding the extra addresses as `/32` so that it's clear you have a primary address.

Comment: @wurtel What value does the concept of a "primary" address bring to anything?

Comment: It's what's used as the default outgoing address, for starters.

Comment: Source address selection *really* doesn't work like that.

Comment: However, in lieu of policy based routing rules, that's what happens. So why not use /32 for the extra addresses? What's the advantage of not doing that?

Comment: If you later nuke the primary, you lose all network access, for starters.  Also, using a `/32` to mark an address as "secondary" isn't necessary, since there's a `secondary` flag available for this purpose.